# FB OAuth returns access token but no expires value

Tags: oauth, facebook-oauth

**Description**:

I have a problem with the OAuth service "randomly" not returning the "expires" value.

The application uses Server-Side Authentication with simple WebRequests and Redirects (no SDKs) and is fully conform with the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).

We store the "expires" value in our own database and we use this information to prompt the user to re-authenticate when the accesstoken has expired (or will expire soon).

We do not automate or batch the renewal of accesstokens in any way. Accesstokens are only refreshed through the Server-Side authentication, ie the process is always user-initiated.

Now we have noticed that when we try to refresh some (but not all) of these expired tokens like this, the OAuth service does **not** return an expires value for step 4 even though the user reconfirms that he does indeed wishes to give us permission to access his facebook account. The accesstoken is returned just fine.

Other tokens do not face this problem. The problem seems to occur randomly but **might** be related to some users granting manage_pages permission and others not. This is however speculation and I currently cannot test this.

The problem can be "fixed" by the user manually going to his app settings and deleting our app from them. When the Server-Side authentication is performed next, the OAuth response contains the expires value as expected and so will any subsequent calls to authorize that user.

**Questions**:

- What is or can be the cause for this (undocumented) behavior?
- How can we fix the affected tokens?
- How can we prevent this from happening?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/339375252810525, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251154038319134

Comment: Thank you CBroe, now at least I know this is not something we were doing wrong. (And that FB doesn't really care about this bug)

Comment: WOW! I've just hit this bug some 7 months later and it's still a problem. :-( :-( :-( Now I gotta refactor my app to guess a 60 day expires if it's not present. Bah humbug. It couldn't be that if you request the manage_pages permission you get an unlimited validity user's access_token could? That would be sweeeeet... :-)

Comment: As of august 12th, 2016, this is still happening. I get `expires` key when getting test users , but not when relative to actual production users. Only the actual `access_token` key is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known bug. (See CBroe's comment)